# Codedom and SourceGenerator

Tags: c#, codedom, csharp-source-generator

I am trying to build a SourceGenerator which should utilize Sytem.Codedom. My project File looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;DebugGenerator</Configurations>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)Generated</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet5/nuget/v3/index.json ;$(RestoreAdditionalProjectSources)</RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='DebugGenerator|AnyCPU'">
      <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUGGENERATOR</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="3.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.CodeDom" Version="5.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\AutomaticInterfaceAttribute\AutomaticInterfaceAttribute.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```

When I try to run Code like this:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.CodeDom;


namespace AutomaticInterface
{
    [Generator]
    public class AutomaticInterfaceGenerator: ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {

            new CodeNamespace("test");

         
        }

       

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            // Register a syntax receiver that will be created for each generation pass
            context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new SyntaxReceiver());

  if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
  {
    Debugger.Launch();
  }
        }
   
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Created on demand before each generation pass
    /// </summary>
    class SyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
    {
        public List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> CandidateClasses { get; } = new List<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Called for every syntax node in the compilation, we can inspect the nodes and save any information useful for generation
        /// </summary>
        public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
        {
            // any field with at least one attribute is a candidate for property generation
            if (syntaxNode is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclarationSyntax
                && classDeclarationSyntax.AttributeLists.Count > 0)
            {
                CandidateClasses.Add(classDeclarationSyntax);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting no generated source and the analzer fails with this error:

```
Warning CS8785  Generator 'AutomaticInterfaceGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'FileNotFoundException' with message 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.CodeDom, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Why does this fail at all?

Comment: Source generators cannot depend on NuGet packages -- they need to bundle their dependencies. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages

Comment: @canton7 thanks, I was not aware of that.